# Gramian matrix of vector linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

$M\in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ is Gramian matrix of some system of linearly independent vectors $x_1,...,x_n$ in euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then:
a. if $M=I_n$ then $x_1,...,x_n$ is orthonormal.
b. if $x_1,...,x_n$ is orthogonal then $M$ is diagonal.
c. $M$ is nonsingular.

c. it is true, it is equivalent to linearly independent vectors (columns)
a. It is true - it is fairly obvious. 
b. it if false,  look
$([1,1], [-1,1])$ is  linearly independent
$\langle [1,1], [-1,1]\rangle = 1\cdot (-1) + 1 \cdot 1 = 0 $  are orthogonal.
$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 \\
    1 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}
$ is not diagonal.

Could you check my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark: I used $v_i$ instead of $x_i$.

Note that the entry of the Gramian matrix are given by
$$a_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle,$$
so if you choose the vectors $v_1=(1,1), v_2=(1,-1)$ the entries are 
$$a_{11}=\langle v_1,v_1\rangle=1^2+1^2=2,\\\  a_{12}=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle=1\cdot 1+1\cdot(-1)=0=a_{21}\\ a_{22}=\langle v_2,v_2\rangle=(-1)^2+(-1)^2=2.$$
So your calculation is incorrect.

I presume that the error in you interpretation is the following: $v_i$ refers to the $i$-th vector and not to the $i$-th component of the vector.

So returning to your original problem $b)$, it clear that if the $v_i$'s are pairwise orthogonal, then by the very definition of orthogonality $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=0$ for $i\neq j$, which is the result claimed.

$a)$ is true

$c)$ you also need to reinterpret using the correct definition given above. So you need to provide a correct proof. But as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix suggests, it is indeed true.

Comment: what about a. and c.

Comment: c. is true due to following theorem:  $v_1,...,v_n$ is linearly independent if only and only Gramian matrix for $v_1,..,v_n$ is nonsingular. Yeah ?